# Canvas element not maintaining height of parent Div

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a `<canvas>` in a div and in order to keep its bounds equal to the div I'm using the following code (I'm creating some of my html/css using Javascript for unrelated reasons, I assume doing in JS should be equivalent).

when I create and add the canvas:

```
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
    this.canvasContainerDiv.appendChild(this.canvas)
    this.canvas.style.backgroundColor = "orange"
    this.canvas.style.width = "100%"
    this.canvas.style.height = "100%"
    this.canvas.width = this.canvasContainerDiv.clientWidth
    this.canvas.height = this.canvasContainerDiv.clientHeight
```

Then in the window resize callback:

```
window.onresize = (e) => {
        this.canvas.width = this.canvasContainerDiv.clientHeight
        this.canvas.height = this.canvasContainerDiv.clientHeight
}
```

---

Unfortunately, the canvas doesn't quite fill the bounds of the parent div.  It leaves a few pixels of missing height.  So that if I resize the window such that the parent div is 522, the canvas' `clientHeight` will be 518 or something.  In addition, as I resize the window's height, the canvas will grow in height monotonically.

I have many questions about this.  `1)` is assigning the parent div's `clientHeight` to the canvas' `height` property the right way to keep the canvas' height matching it?  `2)`, can I size the canvas' element to its parent div with css width/height alone? `3)` why does the canvas grow and grow when I resize the window? `4)` why does the canvas' `clientHeight` not its `height` (although that is wrong too) wind up coming out slightly smaller than the parent div's `clientHeight`?  the width's match fine?

Some extra information.  If I replace the canvas with a div element, I don't see either of the problems I mentioned.  The div now spans the exact height of its parent, and doesn't suffer from that infinite height growth issue.  This leads me to believe that the sizing issues are related to the canvas' own functionalities like context/drawing size/height properties, etc..

Comment: Can you post a working HTML/JS snippet?

Comment: i posted what i thought was the relevant code.

Comment: in `window.onresize`, do you mean `this.canvas.width = 
 this.canvasContainerDiv.offsetWidth` instead of `this.canvas.width = 
 this.canvasContainerDiv.offsetHeight`?

Comment: sorry, typo. meant both should be client*

Comment: i'm still working out what `[client/offset][width/height]` properties mean precisely for my needs.

Comment: Well, you're setting `this.canvas.width` to `...offsetHeight`, instead of `...offsetWidth`.

Comment: that sounds like a hack.

Comment: This might be a good time to use `display:table;` on the Parent of the Parent of the canvas Element (make one if you have to), then `display:table-cell; text-align:center;` on the Parent of the cavas Element. Things in table cells are auto vertically aligned.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this before.  Try adding the following styles:

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

I think this has helped me before as well:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

If those don't do the trick, there are all kinds of other weird things that can cause undesirable/unexplainable space, sometimes setting `line-height: 0, font-size: 0` helps

I just remembered something else that might work without any of the above.  Make your canvas `{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0 }`